# Javascript - Arguments passed as objects

Tags: javascript

If Argument passed to a function and argument has a value as an object, then what is the reason its value is updated when the function member is referencing the same value.
May be I confused you but here is the code snippet.

```
function human(member, year){
member.name = 'Bob';
year = '1990';
}
const person = {
    name: 'Sam';
    
}
const birthyear = '2000';

human(person, birthyear);
console.log(person, birthyear);
```

Output : {name:Bob}, "2000"
Doubt is why the heck value of Person changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `non-primitive in javascript are passed via` Call by Reference`. So it's the memory address that is being passed(& a copy isn't created).
However, you can always create a copy if you don't to update it.

```
function human(member, year){
member.name = 'Bob';
year = '1990';
}
const person = {
    name: 'Sam';
    
}
const birthYear = '2000';    
human({ ...person }, birthYear);
```

And the output for the person would still be `{ name: "Sam" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript primitive types are pass by value whereas Objects are pass by reference.

your function :

```
function human(member, year){
    member.name = 'Bob';
    year= '1990';
};
```

Creates a local variable as `year` which does not have any effect on `birthyear`.
Since the variable is scoped to the function change and when you update the assignment, the variable defined in the function scope is updated.

But when you change the function to:

```
function human(member, year){
    member.name = 'Bob';
    birthyear = '1990';
};
```

You will notice the `birthyear` getting changed to 1990 in your output.

Comment: Objects are passed by *reference*; passing by *value* implies that such a thing that you can do in JavaScript would not be possible.

Comment: And the value will be updated in the function's scope only, outside the block it still will be what was passed.

Comment: Yes @sfdcfox for objects its pass by reference and for primitive types its pass by values. Edited my statement for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)